# mutli-task learning keras ( integrate two task in one mutli-ask one)

Tags: python, keras

i work on keras , i have two problem i want to solve ( one classifiecation and other regression ) with the same input and different in output 
for classification all data will be used and also for regression , the difference just in output layer
i create single model for each one as the following example for classification

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu', input_dim=377))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(56, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1))#
```

and it works well , the same model with changing in the last model works well for regression problem
my question is how to integrate the two tasks in multi-task learning neural network that take one input and output the two tasks
i search a lot but i didn't reach to the solution i want 
note : i work with data in CSV file format

any help will be appreciated

Comment: This seems far too broad/vague, and likely off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example with keras functional api

```
inp = Input((377,))
x = Dense(300, activation='relu')(inp)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(56, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)

out_reg = Dense(1, name='reg')(x)
out_class = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='class')(x) # I suppose bivariate classification problem

model = Model(inp, [out_reg, out_class])

model.compile('adam', loss={'reg':'mse', 'class':'binary_crossentropy'}, 
              loss_weights={'reg':0.5, 'class':0.5})
```

I used the structure you reported for classification and for regression, the only difference is in the output: 2 dense layer, one regression and the other classification (I suppose a binary classifier)

I've applied also a different loss for regression and classification. You can also balance them in a different way

Comment: please how to evaluate and return rmse, and binary_crossentropy .. my question how to pass x, y1,y2 for evaluation

Comment: it givers the following error "ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata)"